# Plugin programming: Uploading a file to a specific folder

Tags: plugins, uploads

I’m trying to develop a wordpress plugin for my dorm for different administration purposes.
One of the functions should be to upload meeting summaries into a folder named “referater” in the root of the server/wordpress installation.
I have had an implementation which worked, but it called another php page to upload, and I want to post the information to the same page.
It inserts the data into the database, but the file is nowhere to be found.
And I know I should be using mysqli but the hosting provider does not support it.

This is the code (and I know it is not so well-written, some of it I have borrowed from an earlier volunteer at the dorm; but at first I just want I to work and afterwards I can optimize it):

```
<div class="wrap">

<!------------------------------>
<!--        Start side        -->
<!------------------------------>
<?php if(!isset($_POST['var_uploaded-referat'])){ ?> 
    <h1>Upload referat</h1>
    Navngivningen af bestyrelses referaterne er ligegyldig, dog <strong>skal</strong> det være pdf-filer. <br>
    Filerne bliver automatisk navngivet som "åååå-mm-dd Referat".pdf (uden " " selvfølgelig), når de bliver uploadet til serveren. <br>
    Så hvis datoen for mødet var 5/6 2013, så bliver referat filens navn 2013-06-05 Referat.pdf. <br>

    <!--Form data for møde dato-->
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p><?php _e("Dag: " ); ?><select size="1" name="dag">
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select></p>

        <p><?php _e("Måned: " ); ?><select size="1" name="maaned">
            <option value="01">Januar</option>
            <option value="02">Februar</option>
            <option value="03">Marts</option>
            <option value="04">April</option>
            <option value="05">Maj</option>
            <option value="06">Juni</option>
            <option value="07">Juli</option>
            <option value="08">August</option>
            <option value="09">September</option>
            <option value="10">Oktober</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select></p>

        <p><?php _e("År: " ); ?><select size="1" name="aar">
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
        </select></p>

        <!--Upload form til referat-->
        <label for="file">Sti til referat:</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="var_uploaded-referat" value="Submit">
    </form>

<!------------------------------>
<!-- Upload-script af referat -->
<!------------------------------>
<?php
    } elseif (isset($_POST['var_uploaded-referat'])) {


        // Connects to the database
        $db=mysql_connect("<server>", "<username>", "<password>")or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("akdtu_dk", $db)or die("cannot select DB");

        $date = "$_POST[aar]-$_POST[maaned]-$_POST[dag]";
        $filnavn = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        $allowedExts = array("pdf");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
        if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
            else{
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

                if (file_exists("../../referater/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                } else {
                    $directory = "../../referater/";
                    $newFileName = "$_POST[aar]-$_POST[maaned]-$_POST[dag] Referat.pdf";
                    $target = $directory . $newFileName; 
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"$target");
                    echo '<h1>Referat uploaded</h1>';
                    echo "Stored in: " . "../../referater/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

                    // SQL insertion/query
                    $sql="INSERT INTO ak_refbest (dato,filnavn)"."VALUES ('$date','$newFileName')";
                    mysql_query($sql);
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid file";
        }
    } else {
        echo '<h1>Fejl ved upload af referat</h1>';
        echo 'Prøv igen, hvis problemet fortsætter kontakt netgruppen på xxx@xxx.dk';
    }
?>
```

Comment: That code has no WordPress in it. You can define the upload folder in WP using `define( 'UPLOADS' )`, voting to close this though.

Comment: @Wyck Thanks for the help, but i'm not really sure I understand your solution. As I understand, your solution is to edit the standard upload folder by editing in the wp-config file. But I only want to save some specific filess in this specific folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using basically the same code, but seperate the upload code to an individual php-file.

It's not as beautiful as it could be but it works.